# what's the meaning of ^@, ^I and $ in vi?

Tags: vim, java, vi, context

When I try to use Context.write(k,v) in MapReduce(using Java) to write data to a file ,I find the following contents in file(opened with vi, have :set list):

```
^@R^@u^@n^@^I1$
^@a^@c^@c^@e^@s^@s^@^I1$
^@d^@e^@f^@a^@u^@l^@t^@ 2$
^@o^@u^@t^@^I2$
^@p^@r^@o^@j^@e^@c^@t^@^I1$
^@t^@a^@s^@k^@^I1$
^@w^@i^@n^@d^@o^@w^@s^@^I1$
^@y^@o^@u^@r^@^I1$
```

What's the meaning of `^@` `^I` and `$`? Does `^I` mean `\t`? I know that `$` means the end of the line, but does it mean the enter key, just like `\n`? If so, what's the difference between '$' and '^M' in vi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is the end of line as displayed by `:set list` with the default value of the `listchar` option. `^I` is the tab character.

`^@` is the `null` character.

For some weird reason every meaningful character in your file is prepended with a `null` character except digits and (probably) spaces.

This is not a Vi(m) problem: check the documentation of that method to see if there's a way to output your data without those `null`s.

Answer (score 1):

The file that you opened is UTF-16 or UCS-2 encoded, which is the standard in Java. `vi` (as in real `vi`, not `vim` symlinked to `vi`) can only handle ASCII (or ISO-8859-1?) text. Use `vim`, or convert the file to ASCII (e.g., `iconv -f utf-16 -t ascii <input> <output>`).

Answer (score 0):

If that's Vim behind your `vi` command, you can reload the file with

```
:edit ++enc=ucs-2
```

or directly specify the encoding

```
$ vim ++enc=ucs-2 filename
```

or, if you need to open these files frequently, prepend `ucs-2` to the `'fileencodings'` option, e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Shouldn't vim automatically detect the encoding? Or does it only do that when there's a BOM?

Comment: @pilona: What gets detected is controlled by the `'fileencodings'` option that I've mentioned.